# Converting String to NSDate (2014-07-29T23:45:50.000Z)

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

Need to set the date format for:

```
2014-07-29T23:45:50.000Z
```

Not sure exactly what to use. I am trying:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z"]
```

Not sure on the exact syntax and was wondering if you could help out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote that `T` and `Z` and use `SSS` for the milliseconds:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as following way :

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.'000Z'"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'`. Here Z indicates that this is a UTC timezone.